# Alarm Receiver and Android Manifest

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I've found several tutorials about setting the alarm receiver to send a toast message in set intervals. and i've been following the code and broken down my own project into 3 classes.

the HelloDroidActivity.java is:

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.helloandroid.alarms.MyAlarmReciever;

public class HelloDroidActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public static int RTC_WAKEUP;
public static long INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;

private AlarmManager alarmMgr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello, Krishneel");
    setContentView(tv);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm went off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.d("OnCreate", "abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd");
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 7000, pendingIntent);

}
}
```

also the MyAlarmReciever.java(i am already aware of the spelling mistake on the name):

```
package com.example.helloandroid.alarms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e("onReceive", "ladskjflsakjdflskjdflskjdfslkjdflasdf");
        Toast.makeText(context, "OnReceive alarm test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and the Android Manifest which looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.helloandroid.HelloDroidActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.helloandroid.alarms" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have read that in order to get the project to receive my alarmReceiver java class I need to edit the manifest with a new receiver. but I'm fairly new to XML and dont know which direction to take.

Comment: One of the sites I'm using for a tutorial is [http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129)

Comment: Have a look at this, this one worked for me. http://www.dotkam.com/2011/01/10/android-prefer-alarms-and-intent-receivers-to-services/

Answer (score 4):

There is already a receiver that you have defined in your manifest file. But the name is not correct see the name needs to be the full class name i.e the package.RecieverName. And in your case the name of your receiver is MyAlarmReciever. So the receiver will be defined as follows

```
<receiver android:name=".alarms.MyAlarmReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.helloandroid.alarms" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, the receiver is listening to an action called `com.example.helloandroid.alarms`. But in your `HelloDroidActivity.java` there is not such action is added to the intent.

```
public class HelloDroidActivity extends Activity {
//....
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //....
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReciever.class);
  intent.setAction("com.example.helloandroid.alarms");
  //....
  }
}
```